# PHP object property from class variable?

Tags: php

Why does this work

```
foreach ($items as $i) {
    $dataTitle = $this->dataTitle;
    $title = $i->$dataTitle;
}
```

when this doesn't?

```
foreach ($items as $i) {
    $title = $i->$this->dataTitle;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think its quite a duplicate. I'm not concatenating things for one. I was thinking `$this->dataTitle` was a variable in and of it self; a class variable. With that thinking I didn't understand why it didn't work.

Comment: Nonetheless, it covers the correct syntax you should use for this concept.

Comment: Possibly, but just because two questions have the same answer does not mean they are the same question. Feel free to mark it for close, your choice. I just commented as to why I thought it wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: There are more answers than just the accepted one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this` referes to current object parsed in not obvious order. You need to use `{expr}` notation, to dynamicly evaluate property name.

Try to use `{}` around `$this->dataTitle`:

```
$title = $i->{$this->dataTitle};
```

---

Look at bottom part of last example in [***variable variables***](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) section of manual.

Comment: Bingo. Though why {} and not ()? I thought () was used to group things for order of operations, and that seems to be what is going on here?

Comment: @Justin808 It is not group order operation. It is property evaluation operation.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$title = $i->{$this->dataTitle};
```

Your expression is being parsed as:

```
$title = ($i->$this)->dataTitle;
```

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in SimpleList.php

Comment: Fixed it. An expression after `->` has to be in `{}`.